# Is it mandatory to point to class files and source files for jacoco report generation

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using jacoco jar (not maven plugin) to generate code coverage report. I have created jacoco.exec file by setting -javaagent as jvm option in my server startup script. Now I want to generate coverage report using the coverage exec file and I have access only to application jar but not to source/class files path.

I've gone through all Jacoco report generation options (maven, API etc..) However all these options required to have path to class files(which i dont have access in my case). I'm trying to generate coverage for application jar file where as sources and class files are not available. In that case, is there a workaround to achieve coverage generation.